# C# - deserialize JSON object

Tags: c#

I am trying to bind the following json to a list, note that each string can contain more than one element, so the list would look like this:

red,black

blue

orange,blue,red,black,pink

```
[
 {
    "shoes": [
      "red",
      "black"
    ]
  },
  {
    "shoes": [
      "blue"
    ]
  },
  {
    "shoes": [
      "orange",
      "blue",
      "red",
      "black",
      "pink"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is what I have so far, it's not much:

```
public class Shoes
{
   [JsonProperty("colors")]
   public IList<string> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

within main, I am calling the actual link (unfortunately I can't provide it here)

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{               
    string json = wc.DownloadString(@"JSONlink");
    Shoes shoe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Shoes>(json);
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'xxx' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

I don't have a lot of experience in this area, so any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample JSON contains a list of objects, each an element representing a `Shoe`. The property representing the collection of colours in the JSON is called `shoes` so the class should look like this:

```
public class Shoe
{
   [JsonProperty("shoes")]
   public IList<string> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

You also need to de-serialize to a collection of shoes not a single instance:

```
var shoes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shoe>>(json);
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data model is incorrect compared to your JSON. I would suggest going to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) page and pasting JSON there to get the C# generated class

I already did that for you:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> shoes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C# class is wrong.

Use this class :

```
public class Result
{
    public List<string> shoes { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization :

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{               
    string json = wc.DownloadString(@"JSONlink");
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(json);
}
```

Comment: @john can you explain how ?

Comment: Please check Ale_lipa  answer. It is the same class. I know json.net. It works. If it doesn't, let me know my mistake or error. Directly voting down does not mean you are right.

Comment: [Example](http://rextester.com/SQCYR91576) - See! It fails! Only RagtimeWilly has the right answer.

Comment: No response to the proof that your code doesn't work? Why wouldn't I downvote an incorrect answer? Isn't that the point of downvoting?

Comment: @john I changed my answer. Thanks and yes class was not wrong, it was a mistake in deserialization, Please remove downvote if possible. Thanks again :)

Comment: In light of the correction, I have upvoted your answer.